# Need a CSS hack to get the numbers to not show up on an unordered list

Tags: html, css

I'm using a content management system that places fields within an ordered list, but one of the clients wants the list without numbers. A `CSS` file that I cannot override is preventing me from changing the `list-style-type` to `none` (even if I use the nuclear option, `!important`). If you know of one, I would like a safe CSS hack to make the numbers removed or invisible. Thanks for your time.

Here's your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x3bm8yk7/

**HTML:**

```
<ol class="no-numbers">
    <li>Here's the first item in the list</li> 
    <li>Here's the second item in the list</li> 
    <li>Here's the third item in the list</li> 
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
ol.no-numbers /* Can't change list-style properties */
{
}
```

Comment: list-style:none -- it's not a hack.

Comment: why you can't change them? if there is another rule overriding your values, you can try to use a more specific selector...

Comment: If you can add a class to the list then it is odd that you can't change list-style:none. But you can also use jQuery.

Comment: When css rules have the same specificity, the rules are overriden by the writing order. So make sure that your class comes *after* the evil css file that is causing you trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't change `list-style`, you can try

```css
ol.no-numbers > li {
    display: block;
}
```

instead of the default `display: list-item`.

```css
/* Can't change list-style properties */
ol.no-numbers > li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ol class="no-numbers">
  <li>Here's the first item in the list</li> 
  <li>Here's the second item in the list</li> 
  <li>Here's the third item in the list</li> 
</ol>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can apply it on the `li` elements as well

```
ol.no-numbers li{list-style:none;}
```

Updated demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/x3bm8yk7/3/